# Unable to change link in Excel workbook

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm having problems changing a link in a workbook that contains a moved sheet.

I move two worksheets from a workbook (tempworkbook) called "Analysis Template.xlsx" into a new workbook (_wb), at which point, I then want to change the link that's in those two sheets from tempworkbook to refer to the new workbook they've just been moved into, yet my changelink code seems to have no effect, and i'm positive i've got the paths correct. Why is this? It's not returning any error, it's just when I check the link in excel itself, its still pointing to the original "Analysis Template" workbook.

As I want this to run in the background, i've disabled a few things within the application, could this be why?

```
_xl.Visible = false;
_xl.UserControl = true;
_xl.DisplayAlerts = false;
_xl.Interactive = false;
_xl.ScreenUpdating = false;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook tempworkbook = _xl.Workbooks.Open(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Analysis Template.xlsx", 0, false, 1, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, 9, true, false, 0, true, false, false); //open template XLS file
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet tmp1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)tempworkbook.Sheets["Data"]; //extract 1st worksheet to move
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet tmp2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)tempworkbook.Sheets["Evaluation"]; //extract 2nd worksheet to move

tmp1.Move(Missing.Value, _wb.Sheets[7]); //move 1st worksheet into new workbook
tmp2.Move(Missing.Value, _wb.Sheets[8]); //move 2nd worksheet into new workbook
_wb.ChangeLink(tempworkbook.FullName, _wb.FullName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks); //change link from template workbook to refer to new workbook
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.changelink.aspx) suggests that you probably need to do a loop over all link sources, and update them each individually.

If you were looking to debug the problem, I would strongly suggest you at least confirm that tempworkbook.FullName is the same as the output of LinkSources(_wb).

Haven't done it personally, just trying to help.